# Regex to Write Your Own NGram Tokenizer

Tags: r, regex

I would like to write my own n-grams tokenizer with regular expressions to better understand the algorithm. Unigrams are a piece of cake. `stringr::str_split("words in a brief sentence", "\\s", simplify = FALSE)` works fine as a unigram tokenizer, but applying this concept beyond one word is perplexing. What regex should be used in place of "\\s" to create bigrams or trigrams (Ex: "words in" "in a" "a brief" "brief sentence")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use

```
v1 <- strsplit(str1, "\\s+")[[1]]
paste(head(v1, -1), tail(v1, -1))
[1] "words in"       "in a"           "a brief"        "brief sentence"
```

---

If we want to generalize, an option is

```
library(data.table)
lst1 <- lapply(shift(v1, n = 0:2, type = 'lead'), na.omit)
mn <- min(lengths(lst1))
do.call(paste,  lapply(lst1, head, mn))
[1] "words in a"       "in a brief"       "a brief sentence"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "words in a brief sentence"
```

Comment: This is very clever! I didn't know `head()` and `tail()` could do that! Thinking about it more, I think a unigram is all anyone needs to construct ngrams, since you can just parse the results together (either with head() and tail(), or with a loop for more general cases). Your response helped to convey this idea. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: @ConnorKrenzer if it is more than 2, i.e. for 3, what would be the result

Comment: @ConnorKrenzer I added an option with `data.table`, which would be more genearalizable.

Comment: The code works like a charm and conveys the underlying concept well. Thanks again!